# Laravel Relationship : retrieve product that belongs to user cart from transaction

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, pivot-table, relationship

I have error like this :

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `products`.*, `carts`.`product_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `products` inner join `carts` on

How do i retrieve/access product that belongs to user cart from transaction table?
so this is my class diagram pict
[image]

this is my Transactions table :

```
  public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id','id');
}

public function transactionDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(TransactionDetails::class);
}
```

My User table :

```
  public function transaction()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'user_id');
}

public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class,Cart::class, 
                                'product_id','user_id','id','id');
}
```

For Cart table, i got this :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And to show user current transaction, i use this

```
 $transactionByUser =  Transaction::with('user.carts.products')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: `public function carts()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class,Cart::class, 
                                'product_id','user_id','id','id');
}` This doesn't seems right to me, it should be straight relations accordint to your database instead of `through`.  Just `hasMany`, but generally, user should have one Cart. I don't know if it is a different business requirements, but generally, it should be single cart for single user and relation should be hasOne

Comment: so inside user models, i should change from hasmany to hasone?

Comment: yes, and also, on cart `hasMany` products not belongs to.

Comment: thank you sir,i little bit confused to define cardinality from that class diagram given. can you give me explaination so i can understand that class diagram?

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function cart_items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'carts');
    }
}
```

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'carts');
    }

}
```

And you can sync/attach products to user with:

```
// Products IDS
$product_ids= [1, 2];
// Then use
$user->cart_items()->attach($product_ids); // adds to existing
// OR
$user->cart_items()->sync($product_ids); // only this will be in your cart
```

To get the cart items

```
foreach($user->cart_items as $cart_item) {
    // do stuff
}
```

For logged user you can use

```
foreach(auth()->user()->cart_items as $cart_item) {
    // do stuff
}
```